# Cauchy problem: $x' - \cot(t) \cdot x = 1 - \cos^2(t), x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, cauchy-problem

The problem: $x' - \cot(t) \cdot x = 1 - \cos^2(t), x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$

The solving part:

$$e^{-\int \cot(t)dt}=\frac{1}{\sin(t)}$$

$$\frac{x'}{\sin(t)}-\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}\cdot x = \frac{1-\cos^2(t)}{\sin(t)}$$

$$\frac{x}{\sin(t)}= -\cos(t)+C$$

$$x(t)=-\cos(t)\sin(t)+C \cdot \sin(t)$$

$$x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0 \Rightarrow C=0$$

$$x(t)=-\cos(t)\sin(t)$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The solution looks right to me. I would have explicitly add how you get from equation 2 to equation 3, and, also in equation2, $1-\cos^2 t=\sin^2 t$.

Comment: @Andrei Ok, I only wanted to check whether my solution is correct.